# Get the return of 'type' as human readable string

Tags: python

How do I get the variable part of `type` as a string?

ie:

```
>>> type('abc')
<type 'str'>
>>> type(1)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(_)
<type 'type'>
```

In each case here, I want what is inside single quotes: str, int, type as a string.

I tried using a regex against `repr(type(1))` and that works, but that does not seem robust or Pythonic. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the name by `type(1).__name__`

Comment: Doh! I thought it would not be so obvious!

Answer (score 3):

use the `__name__` attribute of `type` object:

```
In [13]: type('abc').__name__
Out[13]: 'str'

In [14]: type(1).__name__
Out[14]: 'int'
```

Answer (score 3):

How about `... .__class__.__name__`?

```
>>> 'abc'.__class__.__name__
'str'
>>> a = 123
>>> a.__class__.__name__
'int'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `__name__` attribute:

```
>>> type('abc').__name__
'str'
```